# My Private cocospod xcasset not rendering when I installed through testflight (works fine locally both debug and release)

Tags: iphone

This application was made long back and it's been working without problems but now I made small changes using Xcode 13 and the problem is that when i compile on my simulator, devices, everything works perfectly, but when i send the app to TestFlight, the images contained inside the POD xcassets modules don't appear.
I have installed pod and published it several times, not sure where it is going wrong.

Does anyone have any idea of why it's not working when I upload the code to TestFlight?